# How to disable the woocommerce auto complete status in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

Need to change the order change status completed to processing. When order is placed suddenly it took into completed status that's not a thing I want . Status will be changing as per virtual product.

I expect the good and useful support from all yours.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```html
To disable the auto-complete status for orders, you can use the woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status filter. You can add the following code to your theme's functions.php file or in a custom plugin


// Disable WooCommerce auto-complete order status
function disable_woocommerce_auto_complete_status($order_status, $order_id) {
    // Set the order status to "processing" instead of "completed"
    return 'processing';
}

add_filter('woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'disable_woocommerce_auto_complete_status', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Did you create this answer with [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)?

Comment: using from https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-automatically-complete-processing-orders/